# Boot by pendrive in Asus Zenbook 14

Tags: boot, asus

I'm trying to install ubuntu in my Asus Zenbook 14 but I can't boot by pendrive. I tried any configurations in BIOS but anyone resolves. How can I boot by pendrive?

Comment: Welcome! Do you have the option to boot from a USB but it doesn't boot?

Comment: Yes, USB appear but don't boot.

Comment: Try: 1. plug in the pendrive while Windows is running. 2. Hold down the shift key and click on the power button under the start menu. 3. You should see an option to boot from the USB.

Comment: Then you may consider that the problem is your USB, not the bios options. How did you create the USB?